# Why does bitshifting to the right work as division?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science, bit-strings

So I'm trying to understand why bitshifting integers to the right works as division.

Take the number `4200`. If I shift it to the right by 1, it divides by 2.
If I shift it to the right by 2, it divides by 4.
If I shift it to the right by 3, it divides by 8.

Why is bitshifting by 1 the equivalent of dividing by 2? 
 And bitshifting by 2 is the equivalent of dividing by 4 etc.

I understand that it has something to do with the power of 2 and the binary system and the way I look at it is like so

```
Multiply 2 with the index at the power of 2 table
8 4 2 1
```

Let's say I wanted to bitshift by 3, I would then take what's on the 3rd index of the table which is the value `4`, going from right to left, and multiply it by 2. hence why bitshifting to the right by 3 is the same as dividing by 8.

I don't understand why though, and I don't feel like that would be a good answer if I were to face this on a test. Where the question is.. "*Why does it multiply by 8 if you bitshift the value to the right by 3*"

Comment: Do you understand how in base-ten, 4200 shifted right divides by 10 (420) or 100 (42)?

Comment: The same reason that "moving the decimal point" divides or multiplies by ten.

Comment: @Dan I didn't even know that bitshifting by 10 was a thing to be honest.

Comment: @RileyVarga: Well, it's only called *bit*shifting in base two, but the same concept applies in any place-value base.

Comment: What is this "4200" thing? You talk as though it's a number written in _binary_. But then what the heck are the 4 and the 2 doing there?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that's just a denary value, it could of been any number at all really

Comment: When you shift right, the right most bits gets removed entirely from the bitstring. that means if its an odd number (rightmost bit is 1) you are doing "integer division" by two, which is not the same as ordinary division. If it's an even number, the regular division by two is performed. Depending on how many shift-rights you do, this process is repeated. I would suggest looking at binary number, for example an even binary number and see how the zeros are removed after shift-right. Same with odd numbers. I.e. every rightmost bit is destroyed from the bitstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let some number $x$ be given and assume it has binary representation:
$$
x=\cdots b_8b_4b_2b_1
$$
where $b_1,b_2,...\in\{0,1\}$ are the binary digits. Then $x$ can be translated into base 10 by multiplying the rows in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\cdots & b_8 & b_4 & b_2 & b_1 \\
\hline
\cdots & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\longrightarrow x=\cdots + 8b_8+4b_4+2b_2+1b_1
$$
and bitshifting by $3$ would leave us with:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\cdots & b_{64} & b_{32} & b_{16} & b_8 \\
\hline
\cdots & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{array}
\longrightarrow x=\cdots + 8b_{64}+4b_{32}+2b_{16}+1b_{8}
$$
More generally one can say that `x>>3` replaces each term by mapping:
$$
2^n b_n\mapsto 2^{n-3}b_n = \frac{2^n b_n}{2^3} = \frac{2^n b_n}{8}
$$
and even more generally, the operation `x>>k` maps the terms as:
$$
2^n b_n\mapsto\frac{2^n b_n}{2^k}
$$

---

In any base, say $q$, we would have:
$$
x=\cdots d_{[q^3]}d_{[q^2]}d_{[q]}d_{[1]}
$$
where $d_i\in\{0,1,...,q-1\}$ and the table would be:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\cdots & d_{[q^3]} & d_{[q^2]} & d_{[q]} & d_{[1]} \\
\hline
\cdots & q^3 & q^2 & q & 1
\end{array}
\longrightarrow x=\cdots + q^3 d_{[q^3]}+q^2 d_{[q^2]}+q d_{[q]}+1 d_{[1]}
$$
and digit shifting by $k$ places to the right would result in division by $q^k$ (and a floor operation since the rightmost digits drop off).

Comment: So in binary, `b` would be considered either 1 or 0, correct? I'm slightly confused because it looks as if the steps you wrote works for any base, but I could be wrong. Also, step 3, that bitshifts to the left, no? Multiplying the value.

Comment: @RileyVarga: They are $b_i\in\{0,1\}$ for the binary case, yes. For an arbitrary base $q$ digit shifting by $k$ digits to the right becomes division by $q^k$. You are familiar with that in base $q=10$, where shifting the digits say $3$ places to the right is equivalent to dividing by $10^3=1000$.